# Creating a JS library and declare what other libraries in depends on

Tags: javascript, requirejs, dependencies

So I'm writing a php-package which will be put on github&packagist. It generates and writes data to a file, and the package will also come with a js-library which job is to read that data-file and display it to the user.
Now, this js-library depends on other libraries, jquery being one among a couple others.

What would be a clean way of declaring those dependencies?

I don't mind using require.js and I have in fact used it for several other projects. But those projects have been complete "apps", not libraries that others are to include in their projects. So in those cases it was no concern adding dependencies and configuring require.js, and it only had to be done once. But this time I want to be able to include this library with minimal amount of code, preferbly without long instructions on how to load it correctly and what other libraries the developer would need to load in as well.

In short: I want to distribute a library that depends on other libraries, which me or another developer can include in another project with minimal amount of code and without knowledge of what other libraries this one depends on.

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I can't seem to find anything on it. I do find lot of information on how to declare dependencies in main projects, but not in libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

- Bundle your application into a single file(including 3th party libraries)
- Just bundle your application into a single file (without including 3th party libraries)

In both cases you will need to create an automated build. You can use [gulp](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md) to create tasks to concatenate all your files into a single file like `framework.js` and `framework.min.js` files that other developers will import.

You can use If you are using require.js you could use the [gulp-requirejs plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-requirejs) to run the [requirejs optimizer](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html):

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    rjs = require('gulp-requirejs');

gulp.task('requirejsBuild', function() {
    rjs({
        baseUrl: 'path/to/your/base/file.js',
        out: 'FILENAME\_TO\_BE\_OUTPUTTED',
        shim: {
            // standard require.js shim options 
        },
        // ... more require.js options 
    })
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./delpoy/')); // pipe it to the output DIR 
});
```

If you decide to include the 3th party libraries as well, use the [No conflict fucntion](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) to avoid problems if somebody has already loaded jquery.

If you decide to don't include the libraries you can look for some variables in the global scope in your library and throw errors if the dependencies are not available.

```
if(typeof $ === "undefined") throw new Error("Framework requires > Jquery 1.9.0");
```

You can usually find the version of a library with ease, for example in jquery:

```
$.prototype.jquery
```

### Update

I would personally recommend to use [Browserify](http://browserify.org/). If you are using requirejs, you can use [browserify-ftw](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-ftw) to automatically migrate your project from AMD to CommonJS.

The Browserify optimizer will generate a `bundle.js` file that your users will be able to import directly without having to download 3th party dependencies or configuring a module loader.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you! The Browserify solution is a fine one, I'll go with that. I think I was hoping for some kind of unified system where one could state dependencies on packages and only those not already loaded would be downloaded. Kind of like php's composer but for javascript. But I guess no such thing really exists. I guess it's really not that big a deal sending a bundle of all libraries to the client even though they all may already have been loaded separately, but it does feel a tad wrong nonetheless.

Comment: I think is probably better to have a light weight library without including 3th party libraries and just let know the developers in your documentation that some other libraries are required [like for example bootstrap lets developers know that jquery is required](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#jquery-required)